# detecting which rule matched when multiple exists

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have an antlr4 rule with two possible expansions:

```
expr := term + term | term * term ;
```

I want to write a visitor that visit such rule:

```
public T visitExpr (MyParser.ExprContext ctx) { ... }
```

Inside `visitExpr` how can I detect which expanded rule was matched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Label something distinctive to the subrule of interest:

```
expr : term p=PLUS term 
     | term m=MUL term 
     ;
```

or label the subrules

```
expr : term PLUS term #plus
     | term MUL term  #mult
     ;
```

Comment: In the former, the labels will be represented as Tokens in the `expr` context, one will be null, meaning that the other subrule is the one that matched. In the latter, the labeled subrules will be each represented as separate contexts so distinguishing the matched subrule is explicit.